# Different kind of ASP.NET meta:resourcekey expression

Tags: asp.net

I seem to remember when ASP.NET 2.0 was released that meta:resourcekey was a new type of expression and that you could potentially build your own "handler" like mymeta:CustomerLabel="LabelX"

Is that possible? What is that feature called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that I am looking for is called [Expression Builders](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx)